# Outlook VBA VLOOKUP into Excel File

Tags: vba, search, outlook, vlookup

New to Outlook VBA what are my choices if I want Outlook to look into an Excel file's A column for a value and return the B column value? (Same as a VLOOKUP)

```
Option Explicit

Sub LookUpExcel()

Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ExcelFileName As String
Dim ColumnA As String
Dim ColumnB As String

Dim oMsg As MailItem

ExcelFileName = "C:\Users\vfdme\Desktop\test.xlsx"

Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFileName)

ColumnA = InputBox("Please Column A value.") 



'[VLOOKUP / Search function?]



MsgBox (ColumnB)

ExitRoutine:
    Set oMsg = Nothing
    Set exWb = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, use `.Add ExcelFilename` instead of `.Open(ExcelFilename)` so it will open even if someone else has it open. Then dont forget to close it when you are done.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have made the adjustment!

Comment: Now you just need to record a macro that does a `Find` on a range and adjust it to your liking, then add it in the spot it needs to be. There really is no need for a `VLookup`

Answer (score 0):

Got the code to work properly :)
Thanks @braX for the tip.

```
Sub LookUpExcel()

Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ExcelFileName As String
Dim ColumnA As String
Dim ColumnB As String

Dim oMsg As MailItem

ExcelFileName = "C:\Filelocation\Testfile.xlsx"

Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Add(ExcelFileName)


ColumnA = InputBox("Please Column A value.")

ColumnB = exWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(ColumnA).Offset(0, 1).Value

msgbox (ColumnB)

ExitRoutine:
    Set oMsg = Nothing
    Set exWb = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```